# moodle - Customize the list of courses in the dashboard page

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I'd like to modify the list of courses ( course overview ), to modify the display of the courses.

I'd like something like that: [image]

Is there a way to save a thumbnail for each course in the database, and display it in the dashboard of the course list, each course with it's own picture, according to the subject

I have updated the file moodleDir\blocks\course_overview\renderer.php
I added a static HTML image next to each course

Answer (score 1):

In the course settings form there is an option to add images in "Course Summary files"

You can upload an image there and retrieve it in the renderer using the function course_image($courseid) shown in this example:

https://gist.github.com/bmbrands/c1eb21dfa7f491b1205ea0ca806b5493